# How to pass macro variable to PROC SQL on IN statement in WHERE clause on MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sas, sas-macro

I have a table in MS SQL Server that looks like:

```
ID, Code
01, A
02, A
03, B
04, C
...
```

and is defined in SAS as

```
LIBNAME MSSQLDB ODBC 
    CONNECTION=SHAREDREAD 
    COMPLETE='Description=OIPE DW (Dev);DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=Amazon;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=OIPEDW_Dev;'
    SCHEMA='dbo'
    PRESERVE_TAB_NAMES=YES 
    PRESERVE_COL_NAMES=YES;
```

I have a SAS dataset that has records of the same format as MSSQLDB (ID and Code variables) but is just a subset of the full database.

I would like to do the following:

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
   /* If SASDS contains just codes A and B, CodeVar=A B
   SELECT DISCTINCT CODE INTO :CodeVar SEPARATED BY ' ' FROM SASDS;
QUIT;
/* seplist is a macro that wraps each code in a quote */
%LET CodeInVar=%seplist( &CodeVar, nest=%STR(") );
PROC SQL;
    DELETE * FROM MSSQLDB WHERE CODE IN (&CodeInVar);
    /* Should execute DELETE * FROM MSSQL WHERE CODE IN ('A','B');
QUIT;
```

The problem is this generates a syntax error on the values in the &CodeInVar macro variable.

Any idea how to pass the macro variable value to SQL Server in the IN statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a few problems here; hopefully some of them are just transcription errors.

First off, this will not do anything:

```
PROC SQL;
    DELETE * FROM MSSQLDB WHERE CODE IN (&CodeInVar);
    /* Should execute DELETE * FROM MSSQL WHERE CODE IN ('A','B');
QUIT;
```

MSSQLDB is your libname, not the table; you need to define it as MSSQLDB.dbname here.  Perhaps that's just a copying error.

Fundamentally there's nothing explicitly wrong with what you've typed.  I would suggest first identifying if there are any problems with your macro variable.  Put a %put statement in there:

```
%put &codeinvar.;
```

See what that outputs.  Is it what you wanted?  If not, then fix that part (the macro, presumably).

I would say that there are a lot of better ways to do this.  First off, you don't need to add a macro to add commas or quotes or anything.

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
   /* If SASDS contains just codes A and B, CodeVar=A B */
   SELECT DISCTINCT cats("'",CODE,"'") INTO :CodeVar SEPARATED BY ',' FROM SASDS;
QUIT;
```

That should get you &codevar precisely as you want  [ie, `'A','B'` ].

Secondly, since you're using LIBNAME and not passthrough SQL, consider using SQL syntax rather than this entirely.

```
proc sql;
delete from MSSQLDB.yourtable Y where exists 
  (select 1 from SASDS S where S.code=Y.code);
quit;
```

That is sometimes faster, depending on the circumstances (it also could be slower).  If code is something that has a high frequency, summarize it using PROC FREQ or a SQL query first.

Comment: You are right about the transcription error.  Also, thanks for the suggestion on creating the string without the macro.  Finally, I did basically what you suggested at the end and moved the select statement into the IN statement and it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: I am adding a comment as I could not find this answer anywhere else.  1. Use CATS("'", column-name, "'") to create a macro variable holding 'values'.  2. You probably do not need to use a macro variable.  Instead, simply select the list of names as a subsquery within your main query.