# Update SAS 9.1 Program to Connect to SQL Server DB instead of Access mdb

Tags: sql-server, sas

At my job there's a SAS script that connects to a Microsoft Access database to retrieve data to a flat file. I've been tasked with adapting it to connect to a SQL Server database instead. We have SAS 9.1 and I cannot update the version because that's not my decision. Here's the code that connects to the Access database (I've replaced the server name and folder names with generic tags for this post):

```
proc import out=SPONSOR 
   datatable="SPO_LOAD_UNBLIND"
   dbms=ACCESS2000 replace;
   database="\\<Server>\<Folder>\<Subfolder>\PROCESS.mdb";
   memosize=2048;
run;
```

What do I need to do to connect this to a SQL Server database named "DM_C0000" with the same table name as in the Access database ("SPO_LOAD_UNBLIND")?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Set up a DSN entry on your computer through Control Panels>ODBC Connections for starters. Then connect via a libname and you'll get access to the table.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with SAS, so I'm not sure how to do this.  Also, this script will be run by different users from different computers, so a DSN on my local computer won't work.

Comment: @Reeza This kind of question is generally on-topic for Stack Overflow, as long as it's not too server-oriented (ie, if a programmer might have to do something like this, which since I have done it many times I'm sure is true).

Comment: @JeffK627 You need to check your licenses - ACCESS and SQL SERVER are probably different licenses (if you don't connect to both via OLEDB/ODBC, which you don't in the above).  There are 3 or 4 you could possibly use.  Can you check PROC SETINIT and see if you have SAS/ACCESS to SQL SERVER, SAS/ACCESS to OLEDB, and/or SAS/ACCESS to ODBC?

Comment: So, Joe, if you've done it many times - how do I do it? ;)

I'm told we do have that access. Someone said it might be proc sql?

Comment: You need to check PROC SETINIT (run `PROC SETINIT; RUN;` then look at the log).  It reports what you have.

Comment: The trick is getting the connections string correct for your setup and connection. This question has an example of a libname connection. Once the libname is defined a user can access it similar to any SAS datasaet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617877/how-to-pass-macro-variable-to-proc-sql-on-in-statement-in-where-clause-on-ms-sql

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working:

```
proc sql;
   connect to odbc (dsn=<dsn>  user=<userid> pwd=<password>);
   create table SPONSOR as select * from connection to odbc(select * from <database>.<schema>.<table>);
quit ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can connect to all current tables of a SQL Server database with a libname via ODBC.

```
* WITH DSN; 
libname mydata odbc datasrc="DSN Name" user="username" password="password";

* WITH DRIVER (change driver name to your current installation);
libname mydata odbc complete="driver=SQL Server; Server=servername; 
                    user=username; pwd=password; database=databasename;";
```

Just be aware changes to tables in SAS affects live database tables. Additionally, deleting entire library deletes all tables in database (not database itself). Instead, be sure to unassign libname.

Comment: Shameless plug, but I maintain [database scripts](https://github.com/ParfaitG/DATABASE_CONNECTIONS) on  my Github page to connect to file-level databases (MS Access, SQLite) and server-level databases (MySQL, SQL Server). And not just in SAS but other coding languages: Python, PHP, R, and VBA.